# Does TeXShop for Mac have key bindings?

Tags: texshop, keyboard

There's a Macro's and Key Binding option in the Preferences Menu, but the only way to utilize these macros is to click through the menus.

How do I get the good ol' classic <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> -> `\textbf{}` behaviour that I am so accustomed to?

Do I really have to write my own `KeyEquivalents.plist`file? Say it ain't so.

Example:

I have written a block of text and want to mark that entire passage and make it bold. I know I can select Bold from the Macros menu, but is there a keyboard shortcut for this?

Comment: Excellent last question. I don't need key bindings to auto-complete environments/commands when writing. Mostly I write a text section first and then I want to format it. So it would be nice to have the text section selected and then do something like right-click and choose from a menu of formatting commands / environments, URL linking etc.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

### 1. Built-in Short Cuts:

When you pull down the menu items you see the keyboard shortcuts. Here is an example of the `Source` menu:

[image]

---

### 2. Command Completion:

If you simply start typing the command you want

[image]

hit `esc` you get:

[image]

Hitting `esc` again:

[image]

---

### 3. Abbreviations:

Besides command completion there are also abbreviations.
All abbreviations for environments start with a ‘b’. 
For example if you type `\bite` and hit `esc` you get the `itemize` environment:

[image]

---

### 4. System Preferences:

Furthermore, you can always add your own keyboard shortcuts. For example going to `System Preferences → Keyboard`, you can define the `COMMAND-B` option to select the `Bold` pull down (which does not have a keyboard shortcut defined):

[image]

After restart, `COMMAND-B` yields:

[image]

---

### 5. Key-Bindings Editor

Under the `Source → Key Bindings` you can access the key-bindings editor with which (I assume, have not tried this myself) you can set up other keyboard sequences:

[image]

From Page 6 of the `TeXShop Tips & Tricks` which can be accessed from the `Help` menu:

> e.g. pressing Opt-, with a US keyboard layout, usually enters `≤` into your document but with Key Binding enabled `\leq` will be entered. Similarly, with some text selected pressing " will surround the selected text with `` and ''.

### 6. Macros Editor:

From Page 7 of `TeXShop Tips & Tricks`:

> Text macros are simple text substitutions. You can also tell TEXShop to insert any selected text using `#SEL#`, place the cursor using `#INS#` and even put in multiple lines in the macro itself. Then you can assign the text macro to a keyboard shortcut.
>   I like to use `Cmd-B` and `Cmd-I` to insert `\textbf{...}` and `\emph{...}` into the document where ... is any possible selected text. Macros to do that are already under the `Macros → Text Styles` Menu so we need only assign keyboard shortcuts to them. To assign `Cmd-I` to the emphasize macro: open the Macro Editor where the form of the Macros menu appears in the left hand pane; click the emphasize macro found under Text Styles; click the Key insertion box and simply insert a lower case ‘i’ (the Cmd key is assumed and additional modifier keys can be checked off ).

[image]

Comment: Ah, I did not know about the autocompletion part. Is it possible to change the button from 'esc'? I do know that those menu items' shortcuts are visible. But for more common commands such as producing italic, bold, emphasized text, are there any shortcuts?

Comment: @Parham: updated answer.

Comment: It's a general tendency that things that use Ctrl elsewhere show up with Cmd on Mac.

Comment: @MikaelVejdemo-Johansson: It was just my way of referring to commonly known shortcuts; I am aware of Mac shortcut customs!

Comment: check out this tutorial I made, which shows how to do this this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_N5F8ZBywPI

Comment: @macmadness86: Good tutorial. Personally, not sure I like the auto addition of the closing brace after opening, and repositioning of the cursor. Many macros require more than one pair, and I prefer to have _all_ the matching pairs of `{}` before going back and filling in the content. Example, for `\frac`, I'd prefer to have `\frac{}{}` _before_ filling the numerator and denominator.  But others may prefer it the way you have defined it.

Comment: Very helpful answer. To think I'd been typing out `\textit{}` manually for the past year...

Comment: Also, you can get \textbf directly by typing \bf and pressing ESC (called the trigger key). You can change the trigger key to TAB in the Source tab of TeXShop->Preferences. If you really want Cmd-B to give \textbf the easiest thing is to create a simple Macro that contains \textbf{#SEL##INS#} and tie it to Cmd-B: that macro already exists in the default set of macros so it only needs to bound to Cmd-B. I also bind \emph{#SEL##INS#} to Cmd-I.