# Defining Commands With Multiple Meaning

Tags: macros

I have defined a new command in my source code:

```
\newcommand{\IN}{interface}
```

which prints out *interface*, but there are times where I would like it to print *Interface* (with a capital I) or *interfaces* instead, how can I do this without defining 2 more new commands?

Comment: Type `interface'. It's easier.

Comment: Related to egreg's comment, just self-publicity :P, here are two answers related to this topic: [Writing readable LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86504/writing-readable-latex/86576) and [Speedy LaTeXing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84397/speedy-latexing/84407).

Comment: Though of course you can do just about anything with macros, the *best* way to use them is to encapsulate material that is either complicated (involving some algorithmic or typesetting considerations) or changeable (such as semantic markup taking the place of explicit formatting).  Replacing simple, if common, words is probably obfuscating (unless, of course, "interface" is a changeable semantic term).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\IN}[1][0]{%
    \ifnum#1=0 interface\fi
    \ifnum#1=1 Interface\fi
    \ifnum#1=2 interfaces\fi
}
\begin{document}
    \IN, \IN[1], \IN[2]
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

However, as Egreg said, type 'interface' is easy. :)

Answer (score 5):

You may also define a starred command for capitals and simply append `s` for plurals:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\IN}{%
    \@ifstar{Interface}{interface}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Singular: \IN, \IN*
\par Ways to write plurals: \IN s, \IN{s}, \IN{}s, \IN*s
\end{document}
```

`\DeclareRobustCommand` is needed to make the command not fragile, so you don't need to `\protect` it in titles, etc.