# "Show Console" keyboard shortcut in TeXShop

Tags: texshop, keyboard

I am switching over from TeXworks to TeXShop on the Mac and I am finding myself missing the good ol' <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> to open the Console. While I can use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to cycle around windows to get to the Console, this is only feasible if I only have one document open -- if I have more than one document then I can't really use this to switch between the consoles since I would have multiple open, whereas in TeXworks I could just find the `.tex` file window and hit <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>.

However, no keyboard shortcut exists in TeXShop to open the Console. I tried #4 from [this guide for keyboard shortcut bindings on TeXShop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82383), and it works for, for example, Bold and Italic but it does not work for Show Console.

Is there a way of doing this or am I just stuck cycling around using <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>?

Answer (score 2):

It works for me (see image below). Make sure you have the capitalisation *exactly correct* and the keybinding doesn't conflict with anything else defined in System Preferences or TeXShop.

[image]

Comment: Still not working for me -- this is what I'm doing, and it looks like yours: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rlzlh8ofesmwm8a/Screenshot%202014-07-01%2009.44.51.png

Comment: No idea sorry `:(` Blame gremlins.