# Is there a TeXShop Macro to make selected typeset text a certain color?

Tags: color, texshop, keyboard

Suppose I have the following code snippet in my *.tex document ([src](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/dolorem%20ipsum%20color%20sit%20amet) ;-) ):

```
Dolorem ipsum color sit amet.
```

I'd love to be able to select part of that text (e.g. `color`), do something quick and convenient (Macro? Keyboard shortcut? Key binding? Other?) to add something to make the typeset text be colored. In other words, I want a shortcut to turn the above line into the following line:

```
Dolorem ipsum \textcolor{red}{color} sit amet.
```

**Is there a way within TeXShop to quickly change the (typeset) color of selected text without inserting the code manually?** I want to do this frequently, so I want it to be as quick as possible.

This is very similar to [Does TeXShop for Mac have key bindings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82382/does-texshop-for-mac-have-key-bindings), except I want to make the text a particular color instead of making it bold (which has many more possible solutions).

Answer (score 3):

You can create a “red text” Keyboard Binding in TeXShop.

To do so, navigate to the “Edit Key Bingings File…” menu option:

[image: screenshot of key bindings menu]

Next, add the following line (note that the `̉` in the `Input` field is <kbd>OPT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>):

[image: screenshot of Key Bindings Editor window]

Finally, click the “+” button to add it, and click “Save” to save changes and close the dialogue.

Now, whenever I select some text and type <kbd>OPT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, the selected text gets surrounded by `\textcolor{red}{` and `}`, which renders that text red.

#### Notes

- Keyboard Bindings must be enabled for this to work. To check this, ensure that there's a check mark next to the "Toggle On/Off" menu option in the first image above.
- You could presumably use any "input" key binding. I chose <kbd>OPT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> because it wasn't taken, is uncommon enough to not cause a mistake, and because these keys could be easily pressed on my keyboard with one hand.
- It goes without saying that you could change the `red` to a color of your choice.